# How change this nested for loop to map

Tags: apex, trigger, map, loop

[I took this code from another question asked in this site](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/377638/add-opportunity-contact-role-from-account-contacts)

My code is similar to the below. Please say how to change the nested for loop used in this snippet to map.

```java
trigger OpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (after insert, after update) {
    switch on Trigger.operationType {
        when AFTER_INSERT{
            OpportunityTotalAmountHandler.CalculateTotalOpportunityAmount(Trigger.new);
            AddContactRoleHandler.AddOpportunityContactRole(Trigger.new);
        }
        when AFTER_UPDATE {
            OpportunityTotalAmountHandler.CalculateTotalOpportunityAmount(Trigger.new);
        }
    }
}
```

```java
public class AddContactRoleHandler {
    public static void AddOpportunityContactRole(List<Opportunity> newOpportunities){
        Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
        for(Opportunity oppObj : newOpportunities){
            accountIds.add(oppObj.AccountId);
        }

        Map<Id, List<Contact>> mapOfContacts = new Map<Id, List<Contact>>();
        
        for(Contact conObj : [SELECT Id, AccountId, Name 
                                FROM Contact 
                              WHERE AccountId IN :accountIds]){
            if (!mapOfContacts.containsKey(conObj.AccountId) {
                 mapOfContacts.put(conObj.AccountId, new List<Contact>());
             }
             mapOfContacts.get(conObj.AccountId).add(conObj);             
        }
                
        List<OpportunityContactRole> listOfOCR = new List<OpportunityContactRole>();
                
        for(Opportunity opp : newOpportunities){
            if(mapOfContacts.containsKey(opp.AccountId) && mapOfContacts.get(opp.AccountId) != Null)
                for(Contact con : mapOfContacts.get(opp.AccountId)){
                    OpportunityContactRole ocr = new OpportunityContactRole();
                    ocr.ContactId = con.Id;
                    ocr.OpportunityId = opp.Id;
                    ocr.Role = 'Business User';
                    listOfOCR.add(ocr);
                    System.debug('List of OCR: ' + listOfOCR);
                }
            }

            if(!listOfOCR.isEmpty())
                insert listOfOCR;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi, what have you tried already? It would be helpful if you would post your own code, not the code from the other question.

Comment: You've taken the code from the question you linked, but it does not appear that you've looked at the answer on that question (which fixes an obvious flaw in the code). This is a prime example of why you should not just blindly copy/paste code. It's important that you make an honest effort to understand code before trying to use it. The answer on that other question doesn't answer your question, but I still feel that this is important enough to mention.

Comment: Hi, I too have the same scenario which should create opportunity contact role. I was searching map method instead of nested for. Now I'm very much clear from @Derek F answer. He actually understands my question. I must copy the code from its answer. I will correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Nested loops are not inherently bad

In this case, *you cannot avoid the nested loop*.
Further, even if you could, this particular nested loop is not an issue.

### How can I tell if a nested loop is bad?

In most cases, they follow a simple pattern

```
for(Object1 record1 :collection1){
    for(Object2 record2 :collection2){
        if(record1.field1 == record2.field2){
            // do work
        }
    }
}
```

It's the comparison of *every record in one collection* against *every record in a second collection* that's the problem. That ends up wasting a lot of time. If both collections hold 200 records (a very modest amount, in my opinion), then the `if()` in the inner loop is evaluated a total of 40,000 times.

*This* is the situation where a map would help.

```java
Map<String, Object2> object2ByStringField = new Map<String, Object2>();
for(Object2 record2 :collection2){
    object2ByStringField.put(record2.field2, record2);
}

for(Object1 record1 :collection1){
    Object2 record2 = object2ByStringField.get(record1.field1);
    if(record2 != null){
        // do work
    }
}
```

This brings the total number of iterations (over both loops) to 400, a reduction of 100x

### Why can't I avoid my nested loop?

Simply put, it's because you have a collection of records, and each record needs to reference a collection of other records.

A loop is the proper tool to use when you don't know how many items you have in a collection, or if the number of items can change.

Need to process a list of Opportunities?
that's a loop

Each Opportunity can have a (potentially) different number of Contacts?
that's another loop (and one that must be inside of the Opportunity loop)

Comment: Well explained, thanks a lot